# All Build Definitions gone in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer, build-definition

In Visual Studio/TFS 2010, there was an item 'All Build Definitions' which would open the Build Explorer and select 'Any Build Definition':

[image: VS2010]

We have now upgraded to Visual Studio/TFS 2012 and this item seems gone:

[image: VS2012]

I can, however, open a build definition and change the selected to 'Any Build Definition'. This will give me the queued and completed builds. It's this list that I sporadically want, because it includes builds launched by my team members, not just mine.

Is it possible to have a shortcut to all build definitions in the Team Explorer (or somewhere else) in VS2012? Or is is something an admin has to do?

Comment: I haven't used the TFS 2012 yet, but is it possible to right click the "All Build Definitions" and say view builds? In 2010 I can right click the builds folder and it gives me the same result as that of double clicking "All Build Definitions"

Comment: Nope, right-clicking 'All Build Definitions' does nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around on the internet and in Visual Studio, I'm declaring the answer as: No.

It isn't possible anymore. if you do find how, please answer the question and I will mark your answer as the correct one.

I also added an item on the Visual Studio User Voice page: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4659318-bring-back-all-build-definitions-in-team-explore